# delete MongoDB document by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using nodejs, express, and mongodb for a blog and I want to delete a document by id. For example purpose to delete a blog post with the id 52976b1b0855c7e81a6192e9 I would write localhost:3000/blog/delete/52976b1b0855c7e81a6192e9 and then I am routed to to a confirmation page. This all works successfully on the client, but the document is not removed from the database

```
app.get('/blog/delete/:id', function(req, res) {
articleProvider.deleteById(req.params.id, function(error, article) {
    if (error ) callback(error)
      else {
        res.render('confirmation.jade')
      }
  })
});
```

---

```
    ArticleProvider.prototype.deleteById = function(id, callback) {
  this.getCollection(function(error, article_collection) {
    if (error ) callback(error)
      else {
        article_collection.remove({_id: article_collection.db.ObjectID}, function(error, result) {
          if( error ) callback(error)
          else callback(null, result)
        });
      }
  });
};
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Try logging `article_collection.db.ObjectID` and see what you get

Comment: Once you get it working, I would strongly suggest that you change the route to delete a blog from an app.get() to an app.post(). It is not recommended that HTTP GET is used for operations that change/delete data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to convert your id to a proper [`ObjectId`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html)?